# Какой способ Autowired не рекомендован для использования, сами разработчиками Spring и почему?

Tags: java, spring

Какой способ **Autowired** не рекомендован для использования, сами *разработчиками* **Spring** и почему, то есть **почему не рекомендуется использовать** аннотацию @Autowired для внедрения компонентов (я слышал мнение, что не всегда можно использовать такой подход для внедрения зависимостей), и есть еще один, но до конца так и не понял почему ?

Когда мы указываем для **Spring** , какие **beans** он должен внедрять в другие классы, тогда мы например,
используем **@Autowired**.

Но данная аннотация не рекомендована к использованию, а рекомендован **Data Binding**, почему ?.